# SoundManager2 360 player usage with createSound method

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

According to documentation [doc here](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/), dynamically creating sound is like that but how will i create 360 player UI with that script, it only plays mp3 at the background without any UI element

```
var mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
 // optional id, for getSoundById() look-ups etc. If omitted, an id will be generated.
 id: 'mySound',
 url: '/audio/mysoundfile.mp3',
 // optional sound parameters here, see Sound Properties for full list
 volume: 50,
 autoPlay: true,
 whileloading: function() { console.log(this.id + ' is loading'); }
});
```

Thanks